# Can't join FREETEXTTABLE with typeORM functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, full-text-search, typeorm, freetexttable

I'm working on a graphQL backend with TypeORM
I found FREETEXT, CONTAiNS, FREETEXTTABLE and CONTAINSTABLE options for fulltext searching in my SQL database.
As FREETEXTTABLE has a "RANK column, it is more useful and I’m using this option.
I added required settings to the database and by below query it’s working correctly when applying the query directly into the database:

```
SELECT * FROM content
INNER JOIN freetexttable( content , *, 'test text') newtable ON newtable.[KEY] = "id"
ORDER BY newtable.RANK desc 
OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 12 ROWS ONLY
```

But when I try to use it with TypeORM like below I have some errors.

```
import { getRepository } from "typeorm";

let repo = getRepository(Content)

return repo.createQueryBuilder("qb")
.innerJoin(FREETEXTTABLE( qb , *, 'light'), newtable,newtable.[KEY] = qb.id)
.skip(0)
.take(12)
.getManyAndCount();
```

And it returns this error:

```
"Error: Invalid object name 'FREETEXTTABLE( qb , *, 'light')'."
```

Could you please let me know if there is a problem with my code or maybe you know a better option for fulltext search in SQL database

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (Different products have different options.)

Comment: The dbms is Microsoft SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was searching for the same issue. I was unable to find a solution to use FREETEXTTABLE with typeorm, so I had to implement it using raw SQL. using below code

```
repo.query(" RAW SQL ")
```